# Three reads with the same name in the BAM file

Tags: alignment, sequence, bioinformatics, genome

I am dealing with the paired-end BAM file, and come up with many warnings like this:

```
WARNING: Could not find pair for HWI-ST430:177:2:1:4979:15503#0
WARNING: Could not find pair for HWI-ST430:177:2:1:5127:13427#0
WARNING: Could not find pair for HWI-ST430:177:2:1:6521:21452#0
```

I check the warning reads in the BAM file, and find all the warning reads have three reads with the same name. For example:

```
HWI-ST430:177:2:1:4979:15503#0  65  chr32   26100696    60  79M21S  chr5    36697147    0   ACTTTGCAATTTAAGTTTTACTTACTTTTTAACTAATATACATGCCTAAAATTTACAAAAACAATAATAAAAACAACAGAACACTGGAAACATTTTTAAA    >;=<>=<<=======<====;===;=======<=>>>>>><=>>==>>>>=>>>>==>?>=<<==>?>>>?>?==><=?>><=<>>>?>?=>??>?===>    BD:Z:FFHFCIKKIHG@EEEHF??DGGEDGGE???DEEGGEFFFFGDHHHHGGE??FF?DGDG???EDGFGFGGF@@@FEHFEIEGFEEIJJIHBHGLJDD@EF@   MD:Z:79 PG:Z:MarkDuplicates RG:Z:Basenji    BI:Z:FFIECHGIHFEAFEEHEAAFFHDFFHDAAAFEEIHFGGHGGGHHGHHHFBBGFBGGGHBBBFGHGGFGGFBBBGHIGHJGHGHFKJJJJEIKLJGHBGFB   NM:i:0  AS:i:79 XS:i:19
HWI-ST430:177:2:1:4979:15503#0  129 chr5    36697147    60  72M28S  chr32   26100696    0   ATTTGCCCCTGGGCTATTTTTTTCCTNCCATGTAAGATTCCGTTTTAAAAATGTTTCCAGTGTTCTGTTGTTTTTATTATTGTTTTTGTAAATTTTAGGC    ===<=<<<<====<=>========<<!<<<=><<=>>>>>=5=>>>>>>>>>>=>>>==>=>=>>>>=?>=>>>>>>>>=?>=>>>?>>>??>??>;<=>    SA:Z:chr32,26100739,-,36M64S,60,0;  BD:Z:FFG@JKKFFHIIEHIGFF?????EGGEEEGHHEGEEDGFEGEGF??DE???FHEF?EGGHIFFGFEIFGGFG@@@EGGEGGGFHAAAHGJHBJJDDEHHI   MD:Z:26T37T7    PG:Z:MarkDuplicates RG:Z:Basenji    BI:Z:FFFBHHHFFHGGDGHGGEAAAAADFGEEEIHHGHFFFGFEGHHFBBGFBBBGHGFBEGIIIFGFEFHGFHHGCCCHIGHIGHHGDDDIIKIFKJGHGHGH   NM:i:2  AS:i:65 XS:i:21
HWI-ST430:177:2:1:4979:15503#0  401 chr32   26100739    60  36M64H  =   26100696    -79 GCCTAAAATTTACAAAAACAATAATAAAAACAACAG    ===<=>>=>>===>===<=>===========>;===    SA:Z:chr5,36697147,+,72M28S,60,2;   BD:Z:IHHE??FF?EGEF???FEFFFDFGE@@AHHIJFIFF   MD:Z:36 PG:Z:MarkDuplicates RG:Z:Basenji    BI:Z:HGHGBBFFAEGFFAAAEFFEGFEGFABBFGHGGHFF   NM:i:0  AS:i:36 XS:i:22
```

The BAM file is alignment of HiSeq reads aligned to the reference genome using bwa, and use picard to remove redundancy. Base realignments were done using gatk.

My confusion is:

1、Why there are three reads with the same name, but have no relation?

2、Maybe the first two are treated as mate pairs and the third as a single read. So could I just ignore it?

Could eveyone help me? Many thanks for your help!

Comment: cross posted: https://www.biostars.org/p/183773/

Comment: your 3 reads reads have flag 65, 129 and 401. First and second are "Paired and first/Second in pair", the third is a "supplementary alignment". So this is not an error.